# Installing gcc on rhel 6.1

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, gcc

GCC doesn't seem to be installed on my RHEL 6.1 machine. Also, when I did:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

It barfed:

```
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

The same command works fine on rhel 5.5. What could be the problem?

```
sudo yum search gcc
```

Returns:

```
libgcc.x86_64 : GCC version 4.4 shared support library
libgomp.x86_64 : GCC OpenMP v3.0 shared support library

sudo yum grouplist
```

Returns:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Error: No group data available for configured repositories


sudo yum repolist
```

Returns:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
repolist: 0





ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Returns:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  67 Nov 28 06:28 redhat.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 529 Apr 27  2011 rhel-source.repo
```

Comment: Can you paste what you have under /etc/yum.repos.d?

Comment: I edited the question with the output of what you asked

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani And what's in those `.repo` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum install gcc` should work, as you suspect.  Maybe you need to subscribe to a specific channel in RHN but [this gcc advisory](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2011-0663.html) seems to indicate that `gcc` should be available on all of these channels, and I assume you're already subscribe to at least one of them:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop (v. 6)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux HPC Node (v. 6)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation (v. 6)

Comment: How do i check whether i'm subscribed to any of these?

Comment: Let me ask this: have your brought a RH subscription?

Comment: yup. I work in a company and i'm trying to do this in one of their servers

Comment: @Chader Shivdasani: Can you see the system in your RHN ?
For a registered system, "yum repolist all" ran as root should yield, amongst other lines:
rhel-x86_64-server-6                                                                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                           6,909

You can also run, as root, "rhn-register", if the system is already registered, then a "This systems appears to be registered with RHN" will show up.
If the system isn't registered, you can then do it via rhn_register or rhnreg_ks.